# Passing byteArray from Camera to another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera, arrays, adt

I am having a problem passing byte[] data to different activity.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,DrawingActivity.class);

    takePictureBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.takePictureBtn);
    takePictureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    myIntent.putExtra("pic", data);
                }
            });
            inPreview = true;

            startActivity(myIntent);


        }
    });
```

In the DrawingActivity, I have the following:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawing_view);



       byte[] picByte = getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray("pic");
       Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picByte, 0, picByte.length);
       Drawable background = (Drawable)new BitmapDrawable(bm);

   //There is more stuf I do with Drawable in here
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: caused by java.lang.NullPointerException. But I don't want to save it to the phone and pass Uri. I want it to just take the picture and move on to the next level. Like what SnapChat does.

Comment: i wanted to ask if the stacktrace indicates the line at which NPE occurs. Its better to pass the path rather than bytes

Comment: The reason I want don't want to save the image is because, the app is for kids game and they will take many pictures. It's bad idea to download every since taken picture. They will have the option to save, if they want to though. Btw, the NPE is coming from the line: byte[] picByte = getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray("pic");

Comment: then look at the sending part. your data in onpicturetaken could be null

Comment: Yep, the error was in the first activity and I moved the startActivity() inside the onPictureTaken method and it's WORKING fine now. Thanks so much for the help man!